# Laravel Vue js. Почему не обновляется значение в data?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Делаю запрос к api, получаю данные, но когда вывожу их в консоль, они оказываются пустыми, но при выводе в шаблон все нормально. Как мне сделать запрос и иметь уже готовые данные, чтобы работать с ними в при монтировании компонента?

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                statusNew : '',
                progress : 0,
                order_id : '',
                order : [],
                segments : [],
            }
        },
        methods:
        {
            getData() 
            {

                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')

                axios.get("api/orders")
                .then((response) =>{

                this.segments = response.data.segments;
                this.order = response.data.order;
                this.order_id = response.data.order.id;

                if(this.order.status=='awaiting'){
                    this.statusNew = 'Скоро начнет готовиться'
                    this.progress = 25
                }
                else if(this.order.status=='cooking'){
                    this.statusNew = 'Готовиться'
                    this.progress = 50
                }
                else if(this.order.status=='delivery'){
                    this.statusNew = 'Идет доставка'
                    this.progress = 75
                }
                else if(this.order.status=='completed'){
                    this.statusNew = 'Доставлен'
                    this.progress = 100
                }

                });
            },
        },
        mounted()
        {
            this.getData();

            console.log(this.order_id); // пустые

            Echo.channel('orders-tracker.'+ this.order_id)
            .listen('OrderStatusChanged', (order) => {


                this.statusNew = order.status_name
                this.progress = order.status_percent

            });  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Первый вариант:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
 data() {
  return {
   apiUrl: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb'
  }
 },
 mounted() {
  this.init();
 },
 methods: {
  async getData() {
   try {
    const response = await axios.get(this.apiUrl);
    if (response.status !== 200)
     throw new Error('Bad status code');
     
    return response.data.results;
   } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return;
   }
  },
  async init() {
   const movies = await this.getData();
   console.log(movies);
  }
 },
 template: `<span>My component</span>`
});

new Vue({ el: "#app" })
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <my-component />
</div>
```

---

### Второй вариант:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
 data() {
  return {
   movies: [],
   apiUrl: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb'
  }
 },
 mounted() {
  this.loadData();
 },
 methods: {
  async loadData() {
   try {
    const response = await axios.get(this.apiUrl);
    if (response.status !== 200)
     throw new Error('Bad status code');
     
    this.movies = response.data.results;
   } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return;
   }
  },
  afterLoadDataHandle() {
   console.log(this.movies);
  }
 },
 watch: {
  movies: function(value) {
   if (value.length > 0)
    this.afterLoadDataHandle();
  }
 },
 template: `<span>test</span>`
});

new Vue({ el: "#app" })
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <my-component />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы когда выполняете getData, запускается асинхронный запрос к api. Следовательно когда пишите в консоль, ответ от сервера еще не получен. 
Гуглите подробнее принцип асинхронных запросов axios.

Вам нужно использовать await async в данном методе или задействовать переменную со статусом загрузки. Например создать loading со статусом false и когда присвоите все переменные из api, перевести ее в true и в шаблоне выводить данные только когда loading положительный.